# RTK query isSuccess on first api call is always false

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

So I am doing a form validation onBlur and I am using RTK query for calling the api. The problem I am facing is that on the very first API call the `isSuccess` is returning false even though the API return status is 200

```
const [validateUser, { data, isSuccess }] = authAPI.useValidateUserMutation();
  const validateUserDetails = (name, event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.value !== "") {
      let fieldData = {
        fieldName: name,
        value: event.target.value,
      };
      validateUser(fieldData);
      console.log("Is Success: ", isSuccess);
      if (isSuccess && data.errors.status !== 200) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    } else {
    }
  };
```

During the first time validating
[image]

Even though the status is API status is 200 success is returned false but now if I do it again it will return true
[image]
Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `isSuccess` variable you are referring to here is the variable created by the closure of the render *before* you executed `validateUser`. As a consequence, at some point in the future the whole component will rerender and create a new closure. In that new closure, there will also be a `isSuccess` variable, and that new variable will be `true`. But that old `isSuccess` variable is a "snapshot from the past", a value in a closure that will never change.
This is a concept that will happen in React a lot, independently of RTK Query, so you probably better read up on [closures](https://whatthefuck.is/closure).

What you could do here, instead of accessing closure variables, is something along these lines:

```js
const validateUserDetails = async (name, event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.value !== "") {
      let fieldData = {
        fieldName: name,
        value: event.target.value,
      };
      try {
        const data =  await validateUser(fieldData).unwrap();
        // do something with it
      } catch (error) {
        // do something with it
      }
  };
```

Comment: thank you for making it clear and article on closures is also great